# Query multiple custom post types using ratios (or similar)

Tags: wordpress

I'm a bit stumped with this one. I'm using wordpress and I'd like to query multiple custom post types using some kind of ratio and display them on a page.

Let's say I have the following post types:

tweet, project, video & post

At the moment my current query result is flooded with tweets and all the other post types are being pushed down the page.

Is there a way to formulate a query so that (say) 25% of the result is taken up by tweets and the remaining 75% taken up by the other post types? Essentially I'd like to reduce the number of tweets that are appearing in my query result.

I hope that makes sense.

Many thanks

Comment: It might depend on how you want to handle the *extra* tweet posts (the 75% of tweets that you don't want showing in the blog roll).  Do you want to *disregard* them (so they don't show on the main blog roll, but perhaps they would all show in a different, more specific "tweets" blogroll"... Or do you want to *spread them out* into all your other results?  (Keep in mind if you spread them out, they'll be out of chronological order from the other post types).

Comment: Thanks Jared - My ideal situation would be to have projects, videos and posts arranged by date, with tweets scattered among them (even though the tweets will more than likely be more recent than the other posts). Something like *select 5 posts of type project, video & post* then insert a tweet and repeating this until I reach the end... I'm sure it's possible but a bit beyond my knowledge at the moment :) There is no tweets blogroll as such - tweets will only appear within the main blogroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably handle this manually with 2 separate custom queries (using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)).  I'm going to assume you want paging enabled (since it's your only blogroll and eventually this will get very large).  In general, the strategy is going to be:

1) Build two different queries (1 for your projects, videos, and posts... And 1 for your tweets).

2) Setup the ratio you'd like to mix using the `posts_per_page` attribute of your query arguments.

3) Loop each query, but don't output their titles or content just yet, but rather, store each in its own array.

4) Create a *new* array to contain your "shuffled" blogroll.

5) Loop through this *new* array to output the content.

```
$posts_array = array(); // this will temporarily hold your projects/videos/posts
$tweets_array = array(); // this will temporarily hold your tweets

// WP_Query arguments for projects, videos, and posts
$post_args = array (
    'post_type'              => array('project', 'video', 'post'),
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
);

// The Query
$query_posts = new WP_Query( $post_args );

// The Loop will be used to grab the posts and store them in $posts_array
if ( $query_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query_posts->have_posts() ) {
        $query_posts->the_post();

        // here you can use any number of functions inside the loop to get content or metadata about this post
        $posts_array[] = array(
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'permalink' => get_permalink(),
            'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
            'content' => get_the_content(),
            'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail()
        );
    }
} else {
    // no posts found, maybe handle this differently if you wish
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

// WP_Query arguments just for tweets
$tweet_args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'tweet'
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '2',
);

// The Query
$query_tweets = new WP_Query( $tweet_args );

// The Loop will be used for your tweets
if ( $query_tweets->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query_tweets->have_posts() ) {
        $query_tweets->the_post();

        $tweets_array[] = array(
            'title' => get_the_title(),
            'permalink' => get_permalink(),
            'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
            'content' => get_the_content(),
            'thumbnail' => get_the_post_thumbnail()
        );
    }
} else {
    // no posts found, maybe handle this differently if you wish
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

$final_array = array(); //this is the array that'll hold the shuffled post types

// this loop is currently built to assume the "posts_per_page" ratio from above
// edit these to your liking if you want to increase the number of tweets per 10 other posts
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $final_array[] = $posts_array[$i];

    // after the 5th normal post, inject a tweet (we only have 2 tweets, so inject the first one)
    if ($i == 4) {
        $final_array[] = $tweets_array[0];
    }
}

// now that all 10 posts are done, throw in the last tweet next
$final_array[] = $tweets_array[1];

// now output your content in your template
foreach ($final_array as $current_post) {
    // this will be your markup for each post so replace this with the HTML for your own template
    echo '<div class="title"><a href="' . $current_post['permalink'] . '">' . $current_post['title'] . '</a></div>';
    echo '<div class="excerpt">' . $current_post['excerpt'] . '</div>';

    // etc etc with any of your remaining array elements
}
```

I didn't test this code, so treat it sort of like pseudocode.  But the general idea is hopefully clear.

Have fun!

Comment: Hi Jared - you're a legend! After a few tweaks I managed to get it all working they way I needed it to. I'll post my code up soon. Thanks again :)

Comment: @blackbird Thanks for the edit suggestions, I updated my answer with those syntax issues.  Not sure why the mods rejected them.  Good luck in your project!